# Spring Integration: How to send response packet to client in case of exception using error-channel?

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration, inbound

I am using Spring Integration in my project.
Endpoints used in application are in-bound gateway, header based router, transformer, spliter, service activator.

In case of success flow(not any exception), in-bound gateway **reply-channel** getting desired response and client gets that response which is fine but in case of any exception, I want to send customized error response which is not working as per my requirement.

I am using error-channel to accomplish above requirement but not succeeding in that.

Please find my configuration of in-bound gateway, error channel etc.
I have not use any chain in configuration.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundGateway"
    supported-methods="GET, POST" request-channel="requestChannel"
    path="/services/tylv/{requestParam}" reply-channel="responseChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:transformer ref="errorHandler"
 input-channel="errorChannel" method="generateErrorResponse"
 output-channel="responseChannel" />

<bean id="errorHandler"
    class="com.csam.wsc.enabling.integration.transformer.ErrorHandler" />
```

In case of exception , com.csam.wsc.enabling.integration.transformer.ErrorHandler.generateErrorResponse(ErrorMessage) successfully called.This API handle exceptions, generate Error Response Packet but it is not being sent to client, just only HTTP Status Code 200 sent.

Ideally it should be sent because transformer's output-channel is reply-channel of inbound-gateway which is already sending response packet along with status code 200 in case of success (no any exception).

I think in case of error-channel , in-bound gateway reply-channel is not working, but I am not sure.

Please help me in configuring error-channel.

Comment: I'd have to see exactly what `ErrorHandler` does, but this looks like it should work OK. I suggest you turn on `DEBUG` logging and follow the messages through the flow; it should become obvious what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the message's headers before the error reaches the error channel and then you should create a new message with the stored headers and route that new message to response channel.

```
MessageBuilder.fromMessage(errorResponseMessage).copyHeadersIfAbsent(storedHeaders).build();
```